# 404 errors on acces to _wdt/<token>

Tags: symfony, ezpublish

In dev mode, all pages try several times to get `_wdt/<some_token>` via XHR.
`_wdt/<some_token>` reponds with 404.
but if I try to get `_wdt/<some_token>` directly afterwards, `_wdt/<some_token>` reponds with 200 OK.

After a few 404, Sf displays an alert window providing access to profiler which fails generally the first time (404) but works fine after a refresh.

It seems related to web developer toolbar but wdt sometimes appears even with those 404 errors.

Routes are correctly configured in `routing_dev` pointing to wdt. `espublish/logs/dev.log` :

```
request.INFO: Matched route "_wdt" parameters: "_controller": "web_profiler.controller.profiler:toolbarAction", "token": "09cfe9" ...
```

I'm using ezpublish 2014.11 and apache 2 using the documented eZ Publish vhost configuration.

Any idea on how to prevent this ?

Comment: have you solved it already?

Comment: No I haven't. I gave up

Comment: I debugged the ProfilerController and determined that it fires 404 when no profile data was generated.

Comment: please post your composer.json, i just figured out that some bundles can break the entire profile process when there profile extension is dying at serialize()